# Getting ride data from Bosch CX System

Tags: electric-bike, performance-tracking

Recently got a Cube eMTB with Bosch CX system installed. Love the bike, does well for commutes and some bush bashing over the weekend.

Being a nerd, I like my data. Considering the system already reads information as a part of its normal function (as well as Torque so I have heard) is there any way to log this to Strava/IPBike/other fitness apps?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this bike, but can you pair it with a headunit like a garmin or wahoo ?   I wonder if the bike logs the data or if its all instantaneous data which is thrown away if not collected by a head unit.  Does the documentation talk about ANT+ or bluetooth ?

Comment: As far as I can deduce from Bosch's website (www.bosch-ebike.com) they have built-in Bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have since purchased and installed a SpeedBox BT Unit, which offers (besides unlocking of the CX motor) a full snapshot of all parameters. Logging in the app is a little underwhelming, and does not offer GPX/FIT export but at least they are available.

Comment: +1 OP actually came back....

Comment: I'll take my medal by post . From what I can tell after much reading, @ulikus is right in that the CAN is used on these motors, and I believe the SpeedBox intercepts this and/or uses it to write to certain registers etc. Pretty damn pleased with it if anyone is interested in a product like it, but prepared for $$$

Comment: Thought I would add after a few years that I have started the process of reverse engineering the BT protocol used by the SpeedBox device and am trying to use it to re-broadcast as a BTLE-compatible CP/CSC device using a phone (and maybe another device at a later date). Another option I have explored is decompiling the BT app (which looks to use Apache Cordova) to allow exporting of the recorded trip as a fit/gpx file and/or implementing the CP/CSC service there.

Ill keep you posted...

Answer (score 4):

Bosch uses CAN bus for communication between motor, battery, display.

There is no easy way to read data from it.

check out COBI.Bike it may offer some of features you want.

Else you can hack into CAN bus and read data yourself, the protocol was decoded on some german pedalec forums. (but as I remember there is no torque data in it)

Answer (score 3):

Bosch now offers upgraded head units, KIOX and NYON, which enable GPS and power meter, color displays. Some new model year ebikes are coming standard with these new color display/controller units.

You may be able to upgrade a bike with a 4th gen Bosch motor and a Purion or Intuvia controller by swapping in a Kiox or Nyon. However, it can be a complicated wiring job, and depending on your current configuration, might be too laborious to be practical.

If you're in the market for a new Bosch bike, though, make sure it comes with the new head unit!